# How to remove leading zeroes and move the digits to the left most in an integer variable

Tags: format, integer, cobol

So let's say that I have a variable that stores two-digit numbers. `01 my-int PIC 99`. But when `my-int` takes one digit values such as `01`, I want it to take the form `1` when printed in which the digit is always in the leftmost and space on the right. Any ideas about how I should define `my-int` in order to achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define my-int to store the data `01 my-int PIC 99`, then either use an edited `01 my-edit PIC z9` and use `MOVE my-int TO my-edit` and `DISPLAY FUNCTION TRIM (my-edit LEADING)` or (in this special case where you only have one space):

```
IF my-int > 9
  DISPLAY my-int
ELSE
  DISPLAY my-int (2:)
END-IF
```

Comment: Is that `TRIM (my-edit LEFT)` or `TRIM (my-edit LEADING)` ?  IBM Enterprise COBOL uses the latter but they're not always standards-conforming.

Comment: @cschneid LEADING is standards-conforming and correct, I've fixed-edited the answer, thx for the remark